# How can I set the first page as cover in Lyx?

Tags: latex, editor, lyx, cover

I'm writing a document in Lyx, an editor for Latex. Is there any fast way to tell Lyx that I want the first page to be the cover of my document?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section 'Add the Cover Using LyX' in 'How to Create & Publish Your E-Book Using Free Tools' by John McDevitt describes a good way of adding a cover to a book in LyX. I have used it and was positively surprised how well it turned out. See page 61 in the pdf (or page 72 in the Scribd box) here: http://awarewriter.wordpress.com/e-book/

This method makes an external pdf the cover as page 0, so goto page numbers still work in the pdf. It is not exactly what you asked for, but you can get a really good result by designing the cover in a photo/drawing program, exporting that as a single page pdf, and then including it using this method.